# Is it "I won't repeat it again" or just "I won't repeat it"?

Tags: vocabulary

I just want to confirm that whether I should use **repeat again** or just **repeat**, as repeat already means something done again and again.

> 1) "I won't repeat the mistake again."
>   2) "I won't repeat the mistake."

Comment: Pleonasm comes to mind... Or is it Prolixity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the sentences *very* literally there is a difference in meaning.

1. You made a mistake, then you repeated that same mistake. You don't want to make the mistake again so *I won't repeat that mistake again*. This requires you to have made the same mistake at least **twice** (or many more times) to make real sense.
2. You made a mistake. You don't want to make the mistake again so *I won't repeat that mistake*. This requires you to have made the mistake at least **once** (or many more times).

As pointed out by Eric Kowal #2 is always sufficient unless you need to make it clear that you have a tendency to repeat your mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Logic says that 2) is sufficient.

In practice, 1) is very common too, especially in informal speech -- perhaps even more common than 2).

Comment: Which one do you say is perfect or are both right to be used ??

Comment: I would use 2) in formal situations or when writing, and I might use either one when speaking in informal situations.

Comment: So using both are not incorrect you say ?

Comment: @c0deFreak - Where parallel expressions are in common use, but not always in exactly the same situations, it's more useful to apply the measure of *appropriateness* than *correctness*.

Comment: ... and then there's Occam's razor. If one might speak bluntly.